# Convert a hex string into base 36 encoded string and vice versa in Java

Tags: java

I am surfing around from quite some time for a proper solution for the above question.

I could not find the solution for the conversion/encoding in Java language.

I need to encode a hex string into base 36 formatted string.

For example, these are sample inputs and outputs.

ID and reversed B36 encoding

3028354D8202028000000000,CHL58FYDITHJ83VN0G1
3028354D8202028000000001,DHL58FYDITHJ83VN0G1
3028354D8202028000000002,EHL58FYDITHJ83VN0G1

Suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: What's the problem? Where are you struggling with the obvious approach?

Comment: As @KerrekSB alluded to, what have you tried? What has not worked with what you tried? What did you expect and what happened with your current attempt?

Comment: Online conversion
http://www.darkfader.net/toolbox/convert/

Comment: I am not into embedded engineering, so not aware of these conversions in depth.

Could find only

public long decode(final String value) {
     return Long.parseLong(value, 36);
    }

  public String encode(final long value) {
    return Long.toString(value, 36);
  }

But this for decimal types, and hexadecimal string are failing with these.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
String convertHexToBase36(String hex) {
  BigInteger big = new BigInteger(hex, 16);
  return big.toString(36);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @rossum for your help and patience.

I could now do a conversion from hex to base36 and vice-versa as per my requirements.

```
public static String convertHexToBase36(String hex)
{
    BigInteger big = new BigInteger(hex, 16);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(big.toString(36));
    return sb.reverse().toString();
}

public static String convertBase36ToHex(String b36)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(b36);
    BigInteger base = new BigInteger(sb.reverse().toString(), 36);
    return base.toString(16);
}
```

I just did reverse B36 encoding.
Loads of applause to @rossum for his patience and help.